# ansible -- don't prompt for variables if the play is skipped

Tags: ansible

I have an `ansible` playbook with a few plays, and one play is set up like this:

```
- hosts: windows
  vars_prompt:
  - name: "svnuser"
    prompt: "SVN username"
    private: no
  - name: "svnpass"
    prompt: "SVN password"
  tasks:
  - name: "Windows Subversion"
    script: "/root/ansible.password.change/wingen.exp {{svnuser}} {{svnpass}}"
    when:
    - rootpassword is defined
```

The play works correctly... however ...

When I run this playbook on a host not in the "windows" group, `ansible` should know in advance that the play is not going to run.  However, it still prompts me for my variables.

Is there a way to prevent the variables from being prompted when this play is going to be skipped?  The only way I can think of is to split up my plays into multiple playbooks, which I'd rather not do if it can be avoided.

Comment: Please share the answer if you have already. How to disable vars_prompt for skipped plays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour to allow `hosts` manipulation via prompts.

See [issue 28408](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/28408).